# confused with google url indexing

Tags: google, google-search-console, web-crawlers, sitemap, search-results

When enter my site in google like this **site:mywebsite.com** I have seen this below image.

[image]

I have 169 total urls in my sitemap.xml file. It says 102 results found. But, when I go to next page (second page) I have seen this below image.

[image]

Now it shows only 12 results found. I have checked in webmaster tools also. It displays 169 urls submitted & 4 url indexed. I'm really confused. Googlebot index my site urls and didn't show up in Search results.

Why it displays like this 102 results found and then I go to next page it display 12 results only found?

Comment: Google's "site:" search result counts are known to be inaccurate.    Google mucks with those results on purpose to make it more difficult to find lots of information about sites that you don't own or get extra information about your own site such as which pages are most powerful.

Comment: See also: [Sitemap indexed count and Google results difference](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48915/sitemap-indexed-count-and-google-results-difference)